# ctrl+shift+space Not Working in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Starting about a week ago (11/30/2017) I noticed that ctrl+shift+space was no longer working in visual studio (any version) to show the parameter info of a method invocation. I did quite a bit of searching to figure out the problem, especially here on SO, and I couldn't find a solution. I also double-checked my VS settings and even reverted back to an old settings file.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for sharing your findings here on StackOverflow! Your details about finding your own solution are unnecessary to document the question and answer for anyone in the future. It's always best to just give the details that are important to clearly state the question/answer.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I methodically started closing applications to see if another application was stealing the input. My hunch was right and it turned out to be the Microsoft Teams desktop application. It turns out that Teams already has a similar bug open about shortcut keys related to the Polish language not working correctly when Teams is running. Those details are here: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32265802-alt-a-and-alt-s-affecting-polish-character-for-%C4%85

Within the above link there is a link to a beta build that fixes the problem for Polish, and it turns out that it fixes the problem for the ctrl+shift+space shortcut too.

Comment: I used Spy++ to find out, what process registered this hotkey and it turned out that it is Microsoft Teams. After that I googled this thread :)

Comment: I pinged a few folks in the Visual Studio team and they're forwarding the feedback ;).

Comment: Oh, how awful! An application stealing hotkey shortcuts while not in the foreground... Ugh. Thanks for documenting this!

Comment: This was fixed for a week, then broken again. The new item is here: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32504371-ctrl-shift-space-is-not-working-in-visual-stud

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me. I use also Resharper. So I had to reset my VS key bindings and reapply Resharper shortcuts. Only this got me it working. If you do not use resharper then it's enough to only do the first step and reset VS keyboard configuration to default

1. Reset current keyboard configuration (Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard | Reset).
2. Go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus | "Visual Studio"  | Apply Scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I used to press `Ctrl + Shift + Space` to see the method parameters info and I was stuck when it stopped working. But I figured out that default Visual Studio shortcut settings changed, and now it corresponds to the `Ctril + K,P` shortcut. You can see it under `Edit -> IntelliSens` menu. And it is easily changeable to `Ctrl + Shift + Space` under `Tool -> Options` , then `Environment/Keyboard` section.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old question, but seeing that many people have `PowerToys` installed nowadays, try checking your shortcuts assigned to some of its features, especially for `Peek`:

[image: PowerToys - Peek Feature messing with VS param tooltips shortcut]

Disabling `Peek` or changing the shortcut fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was Microsoft Teams that was absorbing the `Ctrl + Shift + Space` shortcut. I've searched the keybinding definitions in Visual Studio 2022 Tools > Options menu, section Environment > Keyboard and unfortunately I did not find any other alternative for the `Edit.ParameterInfo` command:

[image]

I know I could add a custom shortcut of my preference, but I do not want to have a shortcut which is not universal; when I change computer and I go to a different machine, the same shortcut will not be there.

Then, I decided to go by a more universal thing: The menu shortcut for this option (Press `Alt` key to see the respective letters underlined). It is located at menu Edit > IntelliSense > Parameter Info, which results in the `Alt + E + I + P` keyboard shortcut.